# D: Escaping spaces in a string

Tags: replace, escaping, d, phobos

I have a string `"foo bar baz"`, and would like to turn it into `"foo\ bar\ baz"`. Short of the hand-hacking method (call `split`, then re-join with the appropriate separator), is there another way I can do this? Does something like a `replace` function exist in Phobos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, [`std.array.replace`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#.replace)

```
import std.array, std.stdio;
void main()
{
    replace("foo bar baz", " ", "\\ ").writeln();
}
```